# How can i use a while loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a problem using a while loop. My main objective is to simulate a [Fanno flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanno_flow) problem for a case where the length of the tube is longer than required. This means we have to change the Mach number in the middle. My code is the following.

```
clc
clear all
close all

P1=1;
T1=273;
Cf=0.005;
Dh=0.15;
G=1.4;
M1=3.0;

Lxstar=0;
M2=1;
Lx=0;
My=0;
Lystar=0;
tol=.001;
L = 6.0;
error=0;


fp = ((1-M1^2)/(G*M1^2))+((G+1)/(2*G))*log(((G+1)*M1^2)/(2*(1+(M1^2*(G-1)/(2)))))

Lstar=(fp*Dh)./(4*Cf)

while Lstar<L
Mx=(M1+M2)./2


    fp1=((1-Mx^2)/(G*Mx^2))+((G+1)/(2*G))*log(((G+1)*Mx^2)/(2*(1+(Mx^2*(G-1)/(2)))))

    Lxstar= (fp1*Dh)./(4*Cf)
    Lx= Lstar-Lxstar
    My=((sqrt((2+(G-1)*Mx.^2)/(2*G*Mx.^2-(G-1)))));
    fp2=((1-My^2)/(G*My^2))+((G+1)/(2*G))*log(((G+1)*My^2)/(2*(1+(My^2*(G-1)/(2)))))

    Lystar=(fp2*Dh)./(4*Cf)
   error= Lx+Lystar-L
   if error<=tol
       break

   else
       Diff=Lx+Lystar
       if Diff<L
           Mx=Mx+.01
       else
           Mx=Mx-.01
       end
   end
end
```

When I run it goes smoothly - it does everything I want but once it changes the Mx it runs again with the Mx=M1+M2/2 instead of the corrected Mx = Mx+.01 or Mx= Mx-.01

Comment: Well, `Mx = (M1+M2)./2` is inside your while-loop. So it gets redefined in the beginning of each loop.

Answer (score 2):

This line: `Mx=(M1+M2)./2` is executed on every loop iteration, even after you assign the new value to Mx.  You need to move it out of the loop, like this:

```
Mx=(M1+M2)./2
while Lstar<L
  %other code here...
end
```

Then when you assign the new value to `Mx`, it won't be immediately overwritten with the old value.